# Why does 3/3 equal infinity in my JS app?

Tags: javascript

I want to tell a user how many moves s/he won the game in.

The lowest possible guesses to win is 3. So, to calculate win percentage the formula is `var acc = 3/guesses`.

But if the user wins in 3 moves, the number I am getting is `3/3 = infinity`. Instead of 1 or 100%.

Why?

```js
var acc = 3/guesses;

guesses = 3;

console.log(acc);
```

[image: Code block results in vs code]

Comment: What's guesses' value before defining it to 3 on line 13?

Comment: Hi @Felix, I cannot seem to add images to my questions like you have done here. Why?

Comment: Guesses value is `guesses = 0` before assigning 3.

Comment: Then you have your answer. `3/0` is `Infinity`.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation yet to show images directly.

Comment: re images - got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `guesses = 3` **after** you already computed `var acc = 3/guesses;`.

If you assign to `guesses` first it works as expected:

```js
var guesses = 3;
var acc = 3/guesses;

console.log(acc);
```

So in your case, what's the value of `guesses` when `acc = 3/guesses` is performed?

In order to get the result you see, `guesses` would have to be `0`:

```js
console.log(3/0)
```

If it was `undefined`, as it would be if that's all of your code and it's not in strict mode, it would be `NaN`:

```js
console.log(3/undefined)
```